# Using AddTo in a function

Tags: variable-definitions

I want to create a function that will take a variable $x$ and reassign the value $x+2$ to $x$.

So

```
f[x_]:= x += 2
```

However:

```
f[10]
```

yields the *Mathematica* error

> AddTo::rvalue: 10 is not a variable with a value, so its value cannot be changed.

Which makes sense, as I am asking *Mathematica* to assign the value of 12 to 10. So how can I do this so that it changes the assigned value of some variable $x$?

Comment: Because I want to assign the new value of x+2 to x, for further use.

Comment: I realize that now, but that's not what your first sentence says.  It says "I want to create a function that will take a variable x and *return x+2*.", not "I want to create a function that will take a variable and *re-assign its value*."  Could you clarify the post a bit?

Comment: You're right; thanks for your correction.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can set `f` to hold its arguments, like so:

```
ClearAll[f];
SetAttributes[f, HoldAll]
f[x_] := x += 2
```

Then

```
x = 5
f[x]
x
```

evaluates to

```
(*
5
7
7
*)
```

You can also use the third argument of `Function` for this, like so:

```
f = Function[{z}, z += 2, HoldAll]
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's pretend that `f` is going to be a function that will see serious use. For such functions, we must consider not only normal use cases, but also edge cases and outright abuse. And we must also consider how `f` will act in combination with other functions.

For this particular case, we might reason that `f` that, while `f[5]` may be of little value at top level, it makes sense for `1 + f[5]` to evaluate to 8. Further, we might want to handle the edge case where x is value-free in the same way we would handle `f[5]`; e.g. return `2 + x`. And finally we would want to print out a normal looking *Mathematica* style error message for abusive use such as f[] and f["string"].

```
ClearAll[f, x, y]
f::badarg = "f requires a symbol with a value or numeric value for its argument";
SetAttributes[f, HoldFirst]
f[x_Symbol] /; ValueQ[x] := x += 2
f[x : (_Symbol | _? NumericQ)] := x + 2
f[args : ___] := (Message[f::badarg]; Defer[f[args]])
```

*Unit tests*

Normal cases

```
x = 40; {f[x], x}
```

> ```
> {42, 42}
> ```

```
{f[5], f[1 + Sqrt[2]], f[π]}
```

> ```
> {7, 3 + Sqrt[2], 2 + π}
> ```

Edge case (`y` has no assigned value)

```
f[y]
```

> ```
> 2 + y
> ```

Abuse

```
{f["string"], f[{1, 2, 3}]}
```

> f::badarg: f requires a symbol with a value or numeric value for its argument
> f::badarg: f requires a symbol with a value or numeric value for its argument
>
> ```
> {f["string"], f[{1, 2, 3}]}
> ```

Comment: complete treatment